# /bin/bash is not launched when ssh putty is used

Tags: bash, ssh, putty, debian-jessie

I can access to  my rented server using `SSH Putty`. But when I  launch Putty the  `/bin/bash` is  not activated  (for instance,  pressed up arrow is show like `^[[A`  - not last operation, etc.).  How can  I  add `/bin/bash`  to  autostart  when  `PuTTY` is launched?  OS Debian jessie.

Answer (score 0):

The  answer was found in [H.-Dirk Schmitt's answer over at Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50266/125332)

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and relogin.

Comment: I think you need just to logout and then login without restarting

Comment: @karlacio , yes . you are right.

Comment: Which shell did you get by default if not bash? Is this for an ordinary user account or one of the system accounts?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, /bin/sh .  new  created   user.